# Iterate over array of Objects in typescript and display in html

Tags: typescript, angular7

I am fairly new to angular 7 and I have an object like this.

```
this.data = {
   title:"mypage",
   pageContent:{
       fields:{
           history:[{
               sys:{},
               fields:{
                 title:"my book",
                 description:"my description"
               }
           },

           {
              sys:{},
               fields:{
                 title:"book1",
                 subtitle:"description1"
               }
           },
            {
              sys:{},
               fields:{
                 title:"book2",
                 subtitle:"description3"
               }
           }]
       }
   } 
}
```

In the view, I have 3 sections to display each item in the array.

```
<div class="row">

      <div class="row">
      <!-- Display first item in the array -->
       <h3 class="text-center">{{data.fields.title}}</h3>
       <p class="our-history-text text-center">{{data.fields.description}}</p>
       </div>
       <!-- Second item in the array -->
       <div class="our-history-text-small" [innerHTML]="data.fields.subtitle | markdownToHtml" spaLinkTransformer></div> 
        <!-- Third item in the array -->
     <div class="our-history-text-small" [innerHTML]="data.fields.subtitle | markdownToHtml" spaLinkTransformer></div> 

</div>
```

I was wondering if,
1.  I need to use *ngFor in the view to iterate over the array. If so, how can I use index in the view to just display specific items in the list.
2. If I should loop through the array in component, assign it to separate variables and use it in view.
Eg:

```
myHistory: Entry<any>;
this.myservice.fetchAll(locale)
.then(entries => {
    this.myPage = entries.fields;
    this.myHistory = this.myHistory.pageContent.fields.history[0];
}
```

But I get an error  Property 'pageContent' does not exist on type 'Entry'.

Could someone help me with the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `ngFor` to first div class row

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let data of data.pageContent.fields.history">

    <div class="row">
        <!-- Display first item in the array -->
        <h3 class="text-center">{{data.fields.title}}</h3>
        <p class="our-history-text text-center">{{data.fields.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Second item in the array -->
    <div class="our-history-text-small" [innerHTML]="data.fields.subtitle" spaLinkTransformer></div>
    <!-- Third item in the array -->
    <div class="our-history-text-small" [innerHTML]="data.fields.subtitle" spaLinkTransformer></div>

</div>
```

With Property `'pageContent' does not exist on type 'Entry'` error, you need check `Entry` class defined.

Stackbliz demo code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exrzwf

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` is the ideal solution here as you have to write the template only once.

Iterate over the `data.pageContent.fields.history` array using `ngFor`

```html
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of data.pageContent.fields.history; let i = index">
        <h3 class="text-center">{{item.fields.title}}</h3>
        <p class="our-history-text text-center">{{item.fields.description}}</p>
        <p>Index: {{i}}</p>
    </div>
```

I've created am [exmaple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-vhaarish) in stackblitz based on your data

Comment: thanks B45i.But my data object doesn't have the same property.

Comment: @VHaarish You should e posting he same data in the question. People are going to spend the valuable time on the info that you provided and you will be wasting them.

Comment: If you look at the data I have provided, you can see the first object has object properties has title and description where as the second and the third object has title and subtitle.

Comment: Please check the stackblitz example. You can iterate over `data.pageContent.fields.history` the property, since that the one holding array.